# How to reset input value

Tags: javascript, html, ternary

```js
function ageVerify() {
    var age1 = Number(document.getElementById("age1").value);
    var voteable;
    if (isNaN(age1) || document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML == "") {
        voteable = "Please type a number";
    } else {
        voteable = (age1 < 18) ? "Too young":"Old enough";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = voteable;
}
```

```html
 <p>Input your age and click the button:</p>
        
        <input id="age1" placeholder="type your age" />
        <button onclick = "ageVerify()">Verify the age</button>
        
        <p id="demo1"></p>
```

Hi. When I was playing around with conditional (tenary) functions, I have discovered the fun side of it as well as its limit. Right now, if the user does not type a number or anything, they get a message "Please type a number." And depends on they type over 18 or under 18, they will get either "Too young":"Old enough".

Everything was fine until I discovered when I tried to verify the age again with an empty input after putting the number, the innerHTML ("Too young") does not go away or get replaced by "Please type a number" when I don't type anything. It works if I don't put numbers beforehand, but as soon as I put numbers, the message does not go away. Is there any way to loop the function? I hope I explained clearly.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try this: `if (isNaN(age1) || age1 == "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that you are testing the wrong values in your first if statement. Since you are using `Number(document.getElementById("age1").value)` to turn age1 into a number an empty input will never be `NaN`, rather it will be 0. And since the value is already set that won't pass either. That's why it wont change back to your desired text.

Also if your setting the text of the element it is best practice to use `.textContent` rather than `.innerHTML`

Try using the below code snippet instead.

```js
function ageVerify() {
  var age1 = Number(document.getElementById("age1").value);
  var voteable;
  if (isNaN(age1) || !document.getElementById("age1").value) {
    voteable = "Please type a number";
  } else {
    voteable = (age1 < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo1").textContent = voteable;
}
```

```html
<p>Input your age and click the button:</p>

<input id="age1" placeholder="type your age" />
<button onclick="ageVerify()">Verify the age</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Thank you! I learned the differences between textContent and innerHTML as well as innerText.

Comment: @YongJunJung Glad I could help.. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks! Oh I forgot to ask this. Why is there an exclamation mark after | |?

Comment: ! is a negator so it’s essentially saying if not this.

Comment: In this case if there is no value.

Comment: So does it mean
isNaN(age1) = if age1 is not a number 
|| = or
!document.getElementById("age1").value = if there is "no" value?

Comment: The second. It precedes what it is negating. So !document.getElementById(“age1”).value === if there is no value (empty string or null)

Comment: Oh! I see. So ! does the same job as or replaces == " ".

Comment: Exactly. It’s best practice to use the ! in this scenario.

Comment: You can also use it with an equals sign to check against a specific value. As in document.getElementById(“age1”).value != “Old enough”. That will always pass as long as the value is not “Old enough”

Comment: In our case when we precede the whole expression it’s just checking against any value. So an empty string or null will pass. If there is any value it will fail.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips! I wish I can put myself into your shoes!

Comment: Happy to help. Just keep being curious and you’ll be surprised at how much you’ll learn.

Comment: Yeah, being curious is important so I keep learning. Since you have been active on replying my comments, can I bother you for one non-code related question? I feel like I am not a type of person who is going to be "good" or "fast" at coding as I am not good at thinking logically or enjoy mathematics. I enjoy drawing and designing more and look forward to making my website from scratch. The satisfaction of finding a solution I get from people like you is incredible. I do practice everyday on w3school but I get scared when it comes to coding. Any tips on how to boost my confidence?

Comment: That’s a hard one... never be scared of messing up. That’s when you learn the most, when you make a mistake. But no matter how good you get there will always be someone better than you. So just keep coding. Do something everyday and you’ll naturally build your skill set and your confidence. But never get too confident because no matter how good you get, you’ll always have more to learn.

Comment: Also, coding is the easy part. Very easy to learn if you’re willing to put in the work and effort. If you’re a good designer that’s valuable. Something that really can’t be taught. So be confident and be willing to put in the necessary time to get your website looking and acting how you want it to. You’ll get faster with every site you build.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do value my imagination and design skill. It is just they are not as practical as coding that is why I envy people who are good at coding (they get paid more too). There will be always someone who is better than you and always more to learn for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your Javascript function to this one.

```
function ageVerify() {
            var age1 = Number(document.getElementById("age1").value);

            var voteable;
            if (isNaN(age1) || document.getElementById("age1").value=="") {
                voteable = "Please type a number";
            } else {
                voteable = (age1 < 18) ? "Too young" : "Old enough";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = voteable;
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for tips!

Comment: all the best..!!